# Checking if string contains numbers, they are at the end of the string only

Tags: python, regex, string

String may contain only letters, but if it has numbers, they must not have any letters after.  `RYAN93` is valid. `RYAN93G` is invalid.

I tried using a `for` loop to check every character in the string for `.isnumeric()`. If that was true I would check for `.isalpha()`. But that would still check the entire string so I wouldn't get the result I am looking for.

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression?

Comment: Find the position of the last digit. If it's not the last character in the string, the condition fails.

Comment: Is the empty string a valid input? Does the input need at least one letter or can all be digits?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

regex does work but it's overkill for such a simple task. Simply loop from the end to the start of the string; if you start with a string then you shouldn't encounter any numbers. If you start with a number, then you're good to go:

```
strs = ['RYAN93', 'RYAN93G', 'ABCD', 'ABC123GH4', 'RYAN93G93']

def verify(s):
    is_previous_char_numeric = s[-1].isnumeric()
    for char in s[-2::-1]:
        if char.isnumeric() and not is_previous_char_numeric:
            return False
        is_previous_char_numeric = char.isnumeric()
    return True
        
for s in strs:
    print(f"Is {s} formatted correctly? {verify(s)}")
```

I hate doing this but because @OysterShucker couldn't help himself, here is proof that O(n) is better than O(n^2) and regex isn't some sort of black magic.

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect. ie it will identify a text like `ABC123GH4` as valid

Comment: This doesn't work. Feed it `RYAN93G93`.

Comment: also notice that a string like `ABCD` should be valid as it has no numbers

Comment: I was under the impression that if it ends with a number, it's instantly correct. I will update the answer

Comment: I understand your point, but even when writing a regex you still need to consider all the edge cases to create a well-formed regex (the variety of answers above is a testament to that). I know a regex is more convenient and creates cleaner code, but it's definitely overkill and most likely runs slower on longer strings ( I could be wrong but I believe) it uses a dynamic programming table to calculate matches which O(n^2) whereas my solution is O(n) and my solution has early termination.

Comment: That is an insanely unfair comparison; regex compilation and execution is much more than "7 lines of code", it also uses N times more loops and many more branches behind the scenes... look up how dynamic programming works. Also, the same code can easily be converted to C using Cython (with a few more tricks like using ASCII codes rather than .isnumeric() of Python) to still be much faster than regex.

Comment: @OysterShucker instead of learning 20+ languages poorly, learn 3 or 4 well, as that is far more useful. Dynamic programming is a family of algorithms, not a language-specific method. I posted an update, proving the obvious. Again, I don't disagree that regex has its uses and is a very handy tool, but it shouldn't be abused everywhere. Feel free to run the same code/adjust its parameters and share your results.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

strs = ['RYAN93', 'RYAN93G', '93', 'RYAN92G3']


for s in strs:
    if re.search(r'^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*$', s):
        print(s)
```

Prints:

```
RYAN93
```

Comment: This answer will also match just digits which is not the spec that the OP described.

Comment: @OysterShucker, how have you determined that just digits does not comply?

Comment: The very first sentence of the post.

Comment: I read the very first paragraph 10 times, and I don't see how it does  not allow only digits.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I think you are looking at "may" the wrong way. It's not "may" as in "might" but, "may" as in "what is allowed". "may contain only" ~ "only allowed to contain". Also the only exception is to end with digits. This means something must come before the digits.

Comment: `re.search()` should not be used if what you are actually looking for is a [`.fullmatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch); it is more semantical and saves for the need of adding anchors: `re.fullmatch(r'[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*', s)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to accomplish your needs.

`re.compile(r'[a-z]+\d*$', re.I)` - this expression states:

- `[a-z]+` one or more alphabet characters
- `\d*` zero or more digits
- `$` til the end of the string
- `re.I` case-insensitive matching

`match` starts the match from the beginning of the string so, it is unnecessary to specifically state that in the expression.

```
import re

items = ['939393', 'RYAN', 'RYAN93', 'RYAN93RYAN', 'RYAN93RYAN93']

match = re.compile(r'[a-z]+\d*$', re.I).match

valid = [item for item in items if match(item)]

print(valid) #[RYAN, RYAN93]
```